# How to know which button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, button

In my page I have many edit buttons each name starts with "edit" and then some id. I want to know any of my edit buttons is clicked or not.
In details, I have form. In form I have many edit buttons which name starts with "edit" , delete buttons which name starts with "delete" and 1 add button. All are submit buttons. form onsubmit I call JavaScript function in which I want if the button is edit confirm("some text") else submit form.
 How can I do that in JavaScript?
I think give all these buttons same id and then getElementById but then how con I change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simple using jQuery:

```
$(':button').click(function() {
  // reference clicked button via: $(this)
  var buttonElementId = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Try it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/7YEay/

**UPDATE based on feedback in comments**

This is untested/pseudo code:

```
$(':submit').click(function(event) {
  var buttonName = $(this).attr('name');

  if (buttonName.indexOf('edit') >= 0) {
    //confirm("some text") logic...
  }

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

This documentation may be helpful too: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I don't understand how to do what I want using what yu write. I have form in which I hava various buttons. And in form onsubmit I call my function in which I want to know buttons that starts with "name" is clicked or not.

Comment: Is the form submitted via the "name" button?  Or could it be submitted via "name" and other(s)?  Sample code snippet in the question might help us guide you towards a more appropriate answer.

Comment: the form is submitted via the "name" and other buttons. In details, in form i have many edit buttons which name starts with "edit" , delete buttons which name starts with "delete" and 1 add button. All are submit buttons. form onsubmit I call javascript funtion in which I want if the button  is edit confirm("some text") else submit form.

Answer (score 2):

```
function MyOnSubmit(e){
   e = e || window.event;
   // srcElement for IE, target for w3c
   var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
   if (target.id.indexOf("edit") > -1){
     // an edit button fired the submit event
   }
}
```

although i advice you research further to find a better way to handle edit and delete buttons (like making them links with href=editpage.jsp?id=23)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you explain what is e in this function?

Comment: e is the event object, e || window.event is to make sure its browser compatible, some browsers send the event object in the handler, and some populate the event in the window object... and some browsers define the "target" some define "srcElement", u gotta read a bit more about event object in DOM (suggest u start with the IE model, because its better documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535863(v=VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you just answered this yourself...

Each starts with "edit", and ends with a unique ID?
So... $(button).attr("id") would give you that. Store it in a variable? Not sure what you're trying to do..

Comment: can I do that without jquery?

Comment: why do anything without jquery? ofcourse you can do it without jquery.. call a function with onclick and pass it either its ID or pass it itself (this). access it how you normally would in the function. Just that jquery is nicer.

Comment: ok, it's no matter with jquery or not. I rewrite my needs can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

bind click event on all button:

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    if (button.addEventListener) {
        button.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
    }
    else {
        button.attachEvent('onclick', handler);
    }
}
```

in your event handler, get the **Event** object, and then get the target:

```
function handler(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // srcElement for IE, target for w3c
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var id = target.name.substring(4);
    /* your code rely on id */
}
```

Comment: Can't I do it more easy? I just want that my some javascipt funtion return true if button name starts with "edit" is clicked.

Comment: ur ambiguous Aram, clear out something first, your function that is supposed to return "true", when is it being called? on load of page? on some link click? or on the button click itself?

Comment: @Ayyash : No my function is called in form onsubmit . I have form in each many edit , delete buttons and one add. I want to know whether one of my edit buttons is clicked or not.

Comment: then otakustay gave u part of the answer, your solution lies in "event" object, your function should detect "event.target" or "event.srcElement" (different browsers see it differently", and then check [event.srcElement.id.indexOf("edit") > -1] if condition is true, then the button clicked is an edit button

Comment: if you wanna know which button is clicked on **server side**, just associate a unique value with each button, then get the submitted value like `request.getParameter("xxx")`

Comment: @otakustay : No I need to check it in client side in javascript, read my question I edit it and you will understand what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might not have phrased your question correctly. If you are using jquery, locating the button is as easy as `$('#id')`, and if you want to store any information on that button, you can either add an attribute or use `jquery.data` function.

```
$('#id').attr("pressed", "true");
```

Or

```
$('#id').data('pressed', 'true');
```

Comment: I don't use jquery and it easn't matter which is id. I just want that if my button which name starts with "edit" is clicked than my function return true.